# Google Sheets 50 million cell count work around

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to get around the 50 million cell count rule? Can this be done by using 2 separate workbooks?
We have a lead tracking system that we have built in a Google Sheets workbook and with the way our leads get updated we have already hit the 50mil record count in Google Sheets over the past 3 months. Deleting the data is not an option as we have to analyze weekly monthly quarterly and yearly stats.
I am pretty sure [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) would still hit the 50mil cell count limit.
Is there a way around this limit?

**Update**:
So a way to combat the cell limit is to totally delete all columns and rows that you do not use and are empty. Trimming the sheets down to just what you have filled in rows and columns.
Apparently if the cell has no data in it it still counts against your cell count despite it being empty.
This is not a solution per say but it is a way to make sure empty cells are not counting against your cell count.

Comment: there is no workaround for that. maybe try Google BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

***There is no way around this.** According to the Google File Size documentation<sup>[[1]](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603)</sup>, the limits on a Spreadsheet are:*

> ​*Up to 5 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.*

#### Things I Tested:

Starting in 2019 it became possible to edit Office files natively in G Suite<sup>[[2]](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/office-editing.html)</sup> so I thought I'd give it a test. According to the specifications and limits page for Microsoft Office Excel<sup>[[3]](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)</sup>:

> Total number of rows and columns on a worksheet: 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

Which totals `17,179,869,184` cells.

As Spreadsheets that are created *on Google Drive* have the Google Drive limit, I created an Excel workbook on my local machine, with the maximum number of possible cells and uploaded it to Drive to see if it could be edited natively. Unfortunately, while the file uploaded successfully, attempting to open the file resulted in the following page:

[image: Google Sheets (unsurprisingly) unable to open a 17 billion cell Excel workbook]

#### More Information, Workarounds & Similar Services:

Honestly if you need more than 5 million cells in a Spreadsheet (or even 50 million!) then you're not using the right tool for the job. With this much data, you're likely better off using a database or a cloud data warehouse such as Google BigQuery<sup>[[4]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery)</sup> or Cloud SQL<sup>[[5]](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs)</sup>

That being said, if Google Sheets/Spreadsheet workbooks *really is the only way forward for you*, the only thing I can recommend you doing is creating multiple Sheets files, separated into a more appropriate timeframe - each Sheet containing data for just a month. This will take a bit more time to set up (though you can use Apps Script for data migration between the Sheets), but in the long run will mean you will be able to use your data more effectively, and any data processing you need to do will complete within the Apps Script Quotas<sup>[[6]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)</sup>.

#### References:

1. [Google Drive Help - Files you can store in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603)
2. [G Suite Updates - "*Office editing makes it easier to work with Office files in Docs, Sheets and Slides.*"](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/office-editing.html)
3. [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)
4. [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery)
5. [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs)
6. [Google Apps Script - Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: Just to be clear my assumption in my post that importrange would hit this limit as well correct?

Comment: That's right - importrange will hit the same limit as it runs within the Sheet itself. Any higher and it'll either hit out-of-range or it will get truncated. And thank you very much!

Comment: No thank you, I knew someone could verify my theories. I started seeing the down votes and I was like WAT this is a valid question LOL. As always Stack Overflow is part patience waiting for another professional who sees your post and is willing to contribute their knowledge to your problem! It is very much appreciated.